# Node soap unwanted body tag

Tags: node.js, soap, soap-client, node-soap

The wsdl response is returning a tag in the body that I don't want, it's inclusion is causing an error.

Is there any way that i can remove this tag so the body is empty?

```
<soapenv:Body>
<tag:Something xmlns:flat="http://www.somewhere.com/wsdl/">
</tag:Something>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @Thore No, I couldn't find an answer for this.